# Move Filter Code into Controller or Helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, controller, helper

I have application that has a Location and each location can have multiple calendars based on the directional faces assigned to it.

Right now, to filter the correct events that correspond to the calendar, I am rendering them in the 
Location show view

**Location.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: @directional_faces %>
```

**_directional_face.html.erb**

```
<%= directional_face.name %>
<% @filtered_event_strips = directional_face.campaigns.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week)%>
<%= raw(event_calendar) %>
```

This part of the code:

```
<% @filtered_event_strips = directional_face.campaigns.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week)%>
```

is what is allowing the concept of multiple calendars to be displayed and then only showing the campaigns that belong to that calendar based on the directional face being shown.

I would like to move this into the controller or helper verses the rendered partial if possible. Or is okay to leave there?

**More Details**

**calendar_helper.rb**

```
def event_calendar_opts
  { 
   :year => @year,
   :month => @month,
   :event_strips => @filtered_event_strips,
   :month_name_text => I18n.localize(@shown_month, :format => "%B %Y"),
   :previous_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.prev_month),
   :next_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.next_month),
   :first_day_of_week => @first_day_of_week,   
   }
  end
```

**Locations Controller #show**

```
def show
    @month = (params[:month] || (Time.zone || Time).now.month).to_i
    @year = (params[:year] || (Time.zone || Time).now.year).to_i
    @shown_month = Date.civil(@year, @month)
    @first_day_of_week = 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely put that in the controller. If it's a common thing (used by more than 2 views), I would put that on the DirectionalFace model to make it even easier. Kind of like

```
def filtered_event_strips(shown_month, first_day_of_week
  self.campaigns.event_strips_for_month(shown_month, first_day_of_week)
end
```

Also, be careful how many instance variables you're passing to your views. You've got 3 in as many lines. There tends to be an easier way to keep the information in the controller/model. Also, make sure you only use @ when you really need to. For instance, it doesn't really make sense in this context for `@filtered_events_strips` to not just be `filtered_event_strips`.

Comment: This filter is only being used by one Model..the Locations. The reason the call has three levels is because when a campaign is created, it is assigned to a directional face. Event strips is how it is defined in the gem 'event_calendar'. Not sure how to alter that

Comment: When I shift this code into the Directional_Face controller, it gives me an error "undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Well you've got a call to first somewhere that you haven't posted. Post some more code.

Comment: Calls to first seem to be located inside the gem itself: # the first and last days of this calendar month
      if options[:dates].is_a?(Range)
        first = options[:dates].begin
        last = options[:dates].end
      else
        first = Date.civil(options[:year], options[:month], 1)
        last = Date.civil(options[:year], options[:month], -1)
      end